Marking a new mail as a task before save while displaying mail
I create a message from Excel with sender, recipient, subject, message and attachments.
I want to mark the message as a task. I understand that I cannot execute MarkAsTask until I have sent the message.
Sub CreateMailWithRemander()
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim MyMessageItem As Outlook.MailItem
  
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set MyMessageItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MiMensaje
        .Display
        '.ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderPlaySound = True
        .TaskSubject = "Mi seguimiento"
        .Display
        '.MarkAsTask olMarkNextWeek 'Here I need set the date and hour for         the task
        .save
    End With
    Set MyMessageItem = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub

I tested with ReminderTime and FlagDueBy but not valid for this.
I need to simulate the manual Outlook process of opening a new message, selecting Tracking-Customize, marking the Notice check, setting a date 7 days from today and the time at 9:00 and clicking OK.

I need what you see in the next picture. The text in the screenshot is in Spanish because my computer has the system in Spanish.

After sending the message, it will be marked with the following information:
Follow-up. It begins on Saturday, May 18, 2024. Expires Sunday, May 19, 2024. Notice: Monday, May 20, 2024 9:00


I cannot send the message directly since it must be reviewed and personalized. I want this part to be automatic since it is repetitive and always the same.
Is there a way to mark mail reminder task only for me before save while displaying mail?

I got this workaround:
Sub CrateMailAndMarkTaskWithRemindirOnlyForMe()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim MyMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set MyMessage = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With MyMessage
    .Display
    SendKeys "+^(G)" 'to simulate Control + Shift + G for show the task window
    SendKeys "o"
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys Format(DateAdd("d", 7, Now), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "09:00"
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End With
Set MyMessage = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub

It does not seem correct and safe.

Does the reminder have to be on the mail? A task can be created in ItemSend.

.MarkAsTask can be applied in an ItemAdd event after sending, unless the reminder needs to be seen before sending.
